# How to validate required for nested object using yup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, yup

`surveyCategories` is an array which includes both string and objects. I just want to validate this array using `Yup`. The validation condition is given below the if condition.

```
const surveyCategories = values.surveyCategories
  .filter(value => !value.sub.subId)
  .map(catId => value, 10);

const subCategories = values.surveyCategories
  .filter(value => value.sub.subId)
  .map(value => ({
    id: value.sub.value,
    intakeTypeId: value.sub.typeId,
    intakeSubTypeId: value.sub.subId
  }));

if (surveyCategories.includes(4) && !subCategories.length) {
  console.log("Select atleast one intake to link with survey!");
}
```